# Makefile for python with command line args

Tags: python, makefile

I have a python script which I call from the terminal like:
`python myscript.py arg1 arg2 arg3`

Now I want to create a Makefile which will allow calling
`./myscript arg1 arg2 arg3`
to do the same as the first command, but I'm not sure how to do this (mostly because of the additional command line args). How do I write this Makefile?

Comment: Are you using bash or batch? (Windows vs. UNIX).

Comment: using bash, sorry I forgot to mention that

Comment: Then yes you can just use `chmod` or make a bash file with the contents of `python FILENAME.py $1 $2 $3`. Now you can run `./myscript arg1 arg2 arg3` and it will run `python FILENAME.py arg1 arg2 arg3`. Now you just do a "make file" within python.

Answer (score 1):

Include your python path on the first line of your myscript.py

```
#!/usr/bin/python
```

Then make your script executable

```
chmod +x myscript.py
```

You can rename `myscript.py` to `myscript` if you will.

Now you can run it the way you wanted.

Comment: Useful advice, but unfortunately I was told I needed to use a makefile.